# ORA-01790: expression must have same datatype as corresponding expression

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

```
select '' as sys_policy_value_id, '' as value from table(sys.dbms_debug_vc2coll $POLICY_DEF_NAMES$) ap 
UNION 
select TO_CHAR(p.sys_policy_value_id), p.value from policy_value p
```

Here `p.value` is CLOB. So I am getting this exception.

If I use `to_char('p.value')` then I get `numberFormat` exception. If I change `''` as value to `null` as value than I get `ora-00932 inconsistent datatypes expected - got clob`.

Tried with Union All as well but not working.

Answer (score 0):

Used DBMS_LOB.substr(p.value, 4000). It is working.

Comment: "It is working" is incorrect. If `p.value` has more than 4000 characters, then you are truncating it - is that what you need? This is not the right solution; the right solution is to select `to_clob('')` in the first part of the `union`, then select `p.value` as is.

Comment: @mathguy It is working with UNION ALL not UNION. also I have one outer select to combine result of UNION and with that UNION ALL also not working. Do you have any idea?